# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}/(1+x^2) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm looking to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-{ax}^2}}{1+x^2} dx$$
where $a$ is real.

The "obvious" thing to try is a semi-circular contour integral in the upper or lower half plane, but this doesn't work because $e^{-{ax}^2}$ blows up along the imaginary axis.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I see that this question is missing context, so I removed my answer.  Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: @robjohn This is an integral I ran into years ago related to Kirchhoff diffraction.  Wolfram Alpha gives a solution, but I was interested to see a proof.  There's not much more context than that.

Comment: It would be nice to preface the question with that information. I might add some context to my answer and undelete it, as long as Mark Viola doesn't think it is too close to his answer.

Answer (score 11):

Let $F(a)$ be given by the integral

$$F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

for $a>0$.

Then the derivative $F'(a)$ of $F(a)$ is

$$\begin{align}
F'(a)&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-ax^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=F(a)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx\\\\
&=F(a)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{align}$$

Hence, $F(a)$ satisfies the ODE $F'(a)-F(a)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ subject to $F(0)=\pi$.  Solution to that ODE can be written

$$\begin{align}
F(a)&=e^a \left(\pi -\sqrt \pi \int_0^a \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=e^a\left(\pi -\pi \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^{\sqrt a}e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\pi e^a \left(1-\text{erf}(\sqrt a)\right)\\\\
&=\pi e^a \text{erfc}(\sqrt a)
\end{align}$$

where $\text{erf(x)}=\frac2{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is the error function and $\text{erfc}(x)=\frac2{\sqrt \pi}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt=1-\text{erf}(x)$ is the complementary error function.

Comment: This is more of a nitpick, but I think you left out a factor of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ between the first and second line of the final derivation

Comment: (+1) I see that the answer I just posted is similar to yours, only slightly different. If it feels too close, I will delete it.

Comment: I have removed my answer due to the fact that the question is missing context.

Comment: Rob, thank you for the up vote.  Much appreciative.

Comment: @Dylan Nice catch.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @MarkViola: I've undeleted my answer. Let me know if you think it is too close to yours.

Comment: @robjohn Our solutions are quite similar.  I'll leave it to you to decide whether you'd like to keep it.  Hope you're enjoying the holidays.  -Mark

Comment: @MarkViola: Your answer details how to  get the differential equation, mine shows how to solve that equation using an integrating factor. While it is true we can verify that the $\operatorname{erf}$ function satisfies the differential equation, I think it's valuable to show the method of solution. If you want to incorporate, or at least mention, the method of solution, my answer will add little and I will delete it.

Comment: @robjohn Let's keep both.

Answer (score 6):

We need $a\geq 0$ to ensure convergence. Assuming $a>0$, the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-|s|}$ and the Fourier transform of $e^{-ax^2}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}e^{-\frac{s^2}{4a}}$, hence the original integral equals
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{s^2}{4a}-s\right)\,ds = \color{red}{\pi e^a\text{Erfc}\sqrt{a}} $$
which is not an elementary function and depends on the CDF of a normal random variable.

Comment: Nice.  To clarify for those not versed in functional analysis: This argument appeals to the unitarity of the Fourier transform.  The integral in question is the $L^2$ inner product of $1/(1+x^2)$ and $\exp(-ax^2)$.  Taking Fourier transforms of both functions doesn't change the inner product, by unitarity.

Comment: Also, you speak of "inverse Fourier transform" of $\exp(-ax^2)$, which should properly be "Fourier transform", though it doesn't matter in this case, as the two are the same.

Answer (score 2):

We can apply [Feynmann's Differentiation Under the Integral Trick](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/why-is-differentiation-under-the-integral-sign-named-feynmans-trick/6220).

Let
$$
f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Then $f(a)-f'(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac\pi a}$. Multiply by $-e^{-a}$ and get
$$
\left(e^{-a}f(a)\right)'=-e^{-a}\sqrt{\frac\pi a}
$$
Thus,
$$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}
\begin{align}
e^{-a}f(a)
&=\pi-\int_0^ae^{-t}\sqrt{\frac\pi t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\pi-2\sqrt\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{a}}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=\pi-\pi\erf\left(\sqrt{a}\right)
\end{align}
$$
So that
$$
f(a)=\pi e^a\left(1-\erf\left(\sqrt{a}\right)\right)
$$